# LC-3 Program: Tracing the Execution

Tags: loops, assembly, lc3

LC-3 program:

```
     .ORIG x3000
     LEA R1, DATA
LOOP LDR R2, R1, #0
     BRz DONE
NEXT ADD R1, R1, #2
     BRnzp LOOP
DONE HALT
DATA .STRINGZ "1234567"
     .END
```

I know the instruction labeled LOOP executes 5 times and the instruction labeled NEXT executes 4 times but I don't understand why.

When I trace the execution, I count the loop going through 7 iterations. Could someone explain how I can find the number of times the instructions at LOOP and NEXT execute?

Comment: As @tim says, the loop accesses string elements valued 1, 3, 5, 7, and then makes an access 1 beyond the null-terminator end of the string.  Such an access — beyond declared data — is generally considered a logic error (similar to buffer overflow/overruns, though those are associated with writes beyond declared data, rather than reads beyond declared data).

Comment: If you were manually working the loop and mistakenly incremented by 1 instead of 2, you should get 8 executions of instruction at `LOOP`: with values from the string being 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0, and then along with 7 executions of instruction at `NEXT`.

Comment: To make an access beyond declared data (read or write) is a logic error for obvious reasons, and let's also note that we very technically don't know what the result of such an access will be.  A small change to the program would highlight the logic error.  Such a change would be adding another `.STRINGZ` after `DATA`, maybe to print a message to the console.  With that, the incorrect access 1 address beyond the string labeled `DATA` would fetch from that next string, and thus, the loop would continue, unintentionally working through that next string as if the two separate strings were one!

Answer (score 1):

It's because the instruction at NEXT is adding 2 to the pointer, not 1.  You fetch every other digit, so you get 1, 3, 5, 7, and then the zero (assuming uninitialized memory is set to 0).